# How can I define f(x) = x/x in MATLAB (Symbolic Computation)

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

I try with these commands

```
x = sym('x');
f(x) = sym('f(x)');
f(x) = x/x;
```

and

```
f(x) = sym('x/x');
```

, but both of them produce

> f(x) = 1

(yes.. for every real x including 0)

The question is how I can avoid the pre-evaluation in the command "sym",
or there exists another way to handle this problem.

Thank you very much!

update 21.05.2014:

Let me describe the problem a little bit.

Consider

> f(x) = x/x

and

> g(x) = 1

It is obvious that **domains** of `f` and `g` are `R-{0}` and `R` respectively.

The automatic simplification in `sym/syms` may lead to lose some info.

Comment: Take a look at 'mupad' which is part of your matlab license. `f:=x->x/x`.

Comment: Why has this been down-voted? It's a completely valid question. This behavior is clearly confusing and potentially non-obvious in the context of `symfun`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @pabaldonedo is good. It seems that the designers of MuPad and the Symbolic Toolbox made a choice as `x/x` is indeterminate.

If you actually want `0`, `Inf`, `-Inf`, or `NaN`, to result in `NaN` rather than `1` then you can use symbolic variables in conjunction with an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
f = @(x)sym(x)./sym(x);
f([-Inf -1 0 1 Inf NaN])
```

which returns

```
ans =

[ NaN, 1, NaN, 1, NaN, NaN]
```

Or, if the input is already symbolic you can just use this:

```
f = @(x)x./x;
f(sym([-Inf -1 0 1 Inf NaN]))
```

Comment: Let me describe the problem a little bit. Consider f(x) = x/x and g(x) = 1. It is obvious that domains of f and g are R-{0} and R respectively. If "sym" automatically simplifies the input, then some info is possibly lost. Moreover f(0) is mathematically undefined and not an "indeterminate form" (we do not cosider it's limit here).

Answer (score 1):

There is no pre-evaluation in your code. F(x) = x/x is always 1, even for x = 0, Matlab is just simplifying how the function is expressed but there is no pe-evaluation.

I think you should have a look to indeterminate forms to understand why for x = 0, x/x = 1. Have a look to wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: Thank you pabaldonedo for your comment.

The problem is that MATLAB simplify the input before storing to f(x) (which i call pre-evaluation). I want no simplification. Just store the value "as is"

Comment: @epsilonxe That is not available for symfun. They are subject to the same simplification rules as syms.